# Why do I get a gap between my UISearchBar and my UITableView Cell Header when I touch the UISearchBar on iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

These two pictures should explain it. The first shows my `UITableView` normally. The second shows when I touch the `UISearchBar` and it takes focus. Why is there a gap between the cell header and the search bar? Anyone know how to fix this?

iOS 7 is when this occurs by the way. I already have this code:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 23;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have noticed this same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem in my code by removing the following 2 lines of code.

`self.viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` 
`self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Hope that leads you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 7 there is small area on the top of UITableView. This is the header of UITableView. 
Add following code to your controller ( UITableViewDelegate class ).

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```